# Angular service word overloaded: rename one service and another SERVICE on angularjs.org API doc

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

As with most, I am trying learn what differentiates the different service providers in angularjs, {service values, service factories, service services, and service providers}.  You may have just read that as `service services` and thought I was the one who was crazy.   I am not. Angular developers are the ones who are crazy, and they even notated it on the API on providers [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), stating

`Note: Yes, we have called one of our service recipes 'Service'. We regret this and know that we'll be somehow punished for our mis-deed. It's like we named one of our offspring 'Child'. Boy, that would mess with the teachers.`

Well, their misdeed isn't clear enough.  In some cases, I know which one they are talking about, usually because it is written grammatically singular `service`, but in many other cases, it is pluralized, and I don't know which `service` they are talking about, all services, or just service services.

I would like to propose that the API documentation differentiates these two terms by one being ALL CAPS, ie `SERVICE` or `SERVICES` and the other be `service` or `services` or if at the beginning of a sentence, `Service`, or `Services`.  Hopefully you agree too.  The problem is that I can't initiate a pull request to the API, as I don't know which words in the documentation are which.  So I am in a predicament.

How do I get the clarification for the overloaded terms in the API? without asking them on SO for basically every sentence using the term `service(s)`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about wording in the AngularJS API Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is hosted on GitHub here: https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/, you can open up your issue there.

Comment: Couldn't find the repo.   Thanks!